# Ошибка "Код 43" при подключении Видеокарт

Tags: windows, драйвер, железо, видеокарта, видеодрайвера

Доброго времени суток друзья! Подскажите кто знает как решить следующую проблему.
Имеется:

- Мать: ASUS P5CG-MX/1333
- ОЗУ: 4GB DDR2
- CPU C2D E2120
- 2 рейзера подключеннные к интерфейсу pci-e 1x to 4 USB (Это покупалось в комплекте)
- ОС Windows 7 x64 так же мучился с Windows 10 x64
- БП 750W
- 3 видеокарты
  1 видеокарта установлена в обычный pci-e zotac 650ti работает нормально
  2 видеокарты подключены через рейзеры, и тут траблы. В диспетчере устройств определяются GTX580 как и положено, но рядом восклицательный знак на желтом треугольнике.

Мои действия:

- Переустановка системы
- Увеличение ОЗУ
- Полное удаление драйверов и установка по новой
- Исправление ошибок реестра
- Пляска с бубном около системы

Драйвера устанавливаются но криво всё время выдаёт "ошибку 43" Ничего не помогает. Прошу вашей помощи!

Comment: Старые драйверы ставили? Ошибка 43 чаще всего возникает при проблемах с USB, например, по питанию. Если удалить одну карту, подключенную через райзер, работает?

Comment: Ставил разные версии драйверов. Сносил драйвера через DDU  и снова ставил. Патчил, не помогает. Если оставить 1 карту подключённую через рейзер к этому разветвителю тоже самое "Код 43"